# application.worksheetfunction.vlookup in vba does not loop

Tags: vba, excel

I have got the following code. The code is working only for 1 cell, so I think that the looping process does not occur. Can anyone help me figuring out how I can make the loop work?

```
Sub test4()

Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long

lr = Sheets("sheet2").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lr
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("b1") = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1"), Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:g10"), 2, False)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: The looping process does occur, but you are not using the loop variable anywhere, so the observable effect is that the looping process does not occur.

Comment: Could you please help me out to setup the looking process for this code?

Comment: You never explained what you wanted to achieve with the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the `i` as follow in the `For` loop

```
Sub test4()

Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long

lr = Sheets("sheet2").Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lr
        Sheets("sheet2").Range("b" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.vlookup(Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & i), Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:g10"), 2, False)

    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming (by logics of your code) you mean to advance **Column A** and **Column B** by the row number in the `For` loop).

To my preference (only), I declare and set "sheet2" to a variable, and later on use the `With Sht2`, makes the code cleaner to read, and mught eliminate possible errors.

```
Sub test4()

Dim i As Long
Dim lr As Long
Dim Sht2    As Worksheet

' is it "sheet2" or "Sheet2"
Set Sht2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("sheet2")

' finding last row is Column "A"
lr = Sht2.Cells(Sht2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With Sht2
    For i = 1 To lr
        .Range("B" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(.Range("A" & i), Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:G10"), 2, False)
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Joe_ft you're welcome :) mark as answer (or the previous answer) and upvote

Comment: to be fair +1 for you sir :)